# Moving different repositories in only one changing the structures

Tags: git

I've some different repositories that are in the form (they arrives from VSS migration)

```
/object/ProjecName/object(*)
/bin/ProjectName/object
/images/ProjectName/object
```

I wish to move them to

```
/Holder/object (*)
```

where 'object' is the folder specified above.

I need also to keep my history (since some sources have a very long story) and the ProjectName is common to all the repos (object, bin, images, ...).

Is it possible via git commands?